# Unable to access a route parameter through route.snapshot in root component

Tags: angular, angular-routing, routeparams, angular-activatedroute

I want to get token from url but it return null as value.

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {    
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit(){  
    const token = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('token');
    console.log(token);
```

and routing.ts

```
{ path: ':token', component: AppComponent }
```

i want to grab contents after / in url eg: localhost:4200/content-to-grab
any solutions?

Comment: Snapshots are discouraged. Use `route.paramMap.subscribe` to get them.

Comment: @trichetriche where did you get that from?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo My own understanding and trials (and probably some blogs or articles I can't recall on my own) : snapshots aren't updated on same route navigation or URL params changes, while routes rely on observables and are updated constantly-ish.

Comment: so? depending on the use case, accessing the `snapshot` member is completely valid as some members of the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` dont change on navigation events. For example, static values defined through the `data` property of a `Route` definition.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, you might want to have a look at the code inside `ngOnInit` in this [StackBlitz Sample](https://stackblitz.com/github/SiddAjmera/AngularTraining?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fuser-details%2Fuser-details.component.ts). You'll notice that using `snapshot` doesn't give the updated `id`. Also, it's more about making the code uniform so that the the developer doesn't `snapshot.params` on one hand while `subscribe`ing to `route.params` on the other. Most developers aren't really aware about which one to use when. I've personally seen many questions here on SO with the same issue.

Comment: At this point, I'm just assuming that you're the one who downvoted all the answers in this thread. If that's the case, it would be really helpful to specify the reason for your downvote. Please forgive me, however, if that's not the case.

Comment: @SiddAjmera what makes you think that Im not aware of that? You are missing my point; using `snapshot` is not discouraged.

Comment: @SiddAjmera indeed, as most answers will not solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is ok, there is another conceptual issue going on:

**you are trying to associate a *path* to the *root component*.**

Most likely, your *root module* looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(...)
  ],
  declarations:[
    ...
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  boostrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The **first instance** of `AppComponent` instantiated by the framework during the bootstraping step will be used as *root component*, and as a consequence, the injected `ActivatedRoute` will be sort of "disconected" from that route definition of yours.

Furthermore, instances of `AppComponent` resolved through the `RouterOutlet` directive will be aware of your route definition.

You can check this by yourself in the [following stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bh7zdi).

The `ActivatedRoute` instance injected into the first instance of `AppComponent` wont reflect the route parameters in neither async or sync manner.
If you navigate to something like `{url}/#/bla`, a second instance of `AppComponent` will be resolved because of the `<router-outlet>`. The `ActivatedRoute` instance inject into it will reflect the route parameter values, both sync. and asynchronously.

Comment: Hi @Jota.Toledo , sorry for the late response. Actually, I had figured it soon after asking here. Anyways Thanks for the answer.!

Answer (score 0):

Try to grab it like this.

```
this.route.snapshot.params["token"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => { console.log(params.get('token'));})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ngOnInit(){  
    const token = this.activatedRout.snapshot.params.token;
}
```